# Does RSA2048 key modulus have to be exactly 2048 bits long?

Tags: cryptography, key, rsa

Does RSA2048 key modulus have to be exactly 2048 bits long, or does it mean at least 2048 bits and it can be for example 2080 bits long?

Comment: Note that I have asked for migration to crypto.stackexchange.com. If the question is not directly related to programming then don't forget the existance of other sites like crypto and IT security in the SE ecology!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key size of RSA is *defined* to be the size in bits of the modulus. The RSA private exponent may actually be *shorter* than the modulus. So yes, the modulus has to be 2048 bits long, otherwise you'd have a different key size.

One implication is that the highest order bit is *always* set to one. With RSA it is very important to keep in mind that all values are stored as *unsigned* integers.